# WPF StatusBar with single StatusBarItem and ComboBox to fill the entire width

Tags: wpf

I have this bit of XAML:

```
<StatusBar Grid.Row="2">
    <StatusBar.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            </Grid>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </StatusBar.ItemsPanel>
    <StatusBarItem>
        <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding StatusMessages}"/>
    </StatusBarItem>
</StatusBar>
```

StatusBarItem is taking up the entire width of the window but the combobox within it is still taking up minimal width. How do I get it to fill the entire width?

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `HorizontalContentAlignment = "Stretch"` to `ComboBox`.

Comment: HorizontalAlignment did not but HorizontalContentAlignment did - thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
<StatusBar>
    <StatusBarItem HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">
        <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding StatusMessages}" SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedStatusIndex, Mode=OneWay}"/>
    </StatusBarItem>
</StatusBar>
```

This worked